# Why is the the exported file blank?

Tags: powershell

I found this Powershell line that returns a list of users and password expiry dates:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

I have tried to pipe the out put to:

```
Export-Csv -Path .\Passwrd.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

So now it looks like this:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} | Export-Csv -Path .\Passwrd.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This completes but the output file is empty.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi Danny, what is your script path try to run from c:\temp folder.. script works fine.

Comment: Thank you Kemal. I was trying to save the file in the users home directory. Also I was not running the script as admin. It works fine now